# How to add external website links in navigation to gatsbyjs/react site using jsx

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am learning GatsbyJS/React and am pretty new to coding as a whole.  I am utilizing a starter gatsbyjs/React template to assist my learning.

I am just trying to add an additional navigation link on the page which links to an external website, not an internal page.  As the site is written now, the navbar is a stateless function component? (I think) and I can add links to internal pages no problem, but because it puts the website URL before the link I end up with the website URL in front of every navlink I add.  The navigation file is a jsx file. 
 Any help would be appreciated so I can learn.

I tried implementing GATSBYLINK but was unable to get it to implement properly.

Here is a portion of the nav code from the jsx file:

```
const ListLink = (props) => (
  <li className="c-main-nav__elem" >
    <Link 
      to={props.to} 
      className="c-main-nav__link" 
      activeClassName="c-main-nav__link--is-active" 
      exact={true}
      onClick={props.closeMenu}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Link>
  </li>
);  

class MainNav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
    this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      links: [
        { to: '/', text: 'Home', icon: FaMapMarker },
        { to: '/toolbox/', text: 'Toolbox', icon: FaWrench },
        { to: '/playground/', text: 'Playground', icon: FaPaperPlaneO },
        { to: '/contact/', text: 'Contact', icon: FaEnvelopeO }
      ],
      mainNavModifierClassName: '',
      mobileDetailsNav: null
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use html `a` tag to redirect to external urls

```
<a href="htpp://myexternalurl.com">URLNAME</a>
```

Or you can use window.location ="mywebsite.com"

Please find change the `render` method of the `MainNav.js` file as specifed below to achieve as specified in the image

```
  render() {
return (
  <div>
    <ul className={ `c-main-nav ${this.state.mainNavModifierClassName}` }>
      { 
        this.state.links.map((link, i) => (
          <ListLink to={link.to} key={i} testLink={this.testLink}>
            <link.icon />
            <span className="c-main-nav__text">{link.text}</span>
          </ListLink>  
        )) 
      }
      <a href="http://www.gooogle.com"><FaMapMarker /><span>asdasdads</span></a>
      <li 
        className="c-main-nav__elem c-main-nav__elem--close-link" 
        onClick={this.toggleMenu}
      >
        <a href="#" className="c-main-nav__link">
          { (this.state.mainNavModifierClassName) ? <FaChevronUp /> : <FaChevronDown />  }
          <span className="c-main-nav__text">Close</span>
        </a>
      </li>    
    </ul> 
    { this.state.mobileDetailsNav }
  </div>
)
}
};
```

I have use google.com as my external url and `asdasdasd` as my link name please change it as per your requirement

Thankyou and wish you a good luck

[image]

Comment: I tried adding an a tag but it does not appear.  Maybe I just dont know where to add it?

Comment: Can you update the code with your implementation of a tag and how are you rendering the links and how you want the link to be displayed

Comment: You cannot use gatsbylink to redirect to external url, and when using a tag you must specify `http` or `https` based on the url you are redirecting to

Comment: Ok, so if I am using the gatsbylink for the internal sites, can I include an a link tag in the nav at all or is the option to include an external link completely off the table if I keep gatsbylink?

Comment: @MidlifeCoder I have gone through your code and i tried adding a anchor tag in the Main nav and uploaded the picture in my answer(Ignore the stying) If thats the requrement i would update my answer with the code you need

Comment: @MidlifeCoder Please find the link name tadaa in the picture

Comment: Just wanted to thank you very much for your time.  I was able to get it with your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just add **https** / **http** before the domain name in href tag.

```
<a href={\`https://${hostname}\`\} target="_blank" rel="norefferer" >{Link Name}</a>
```

Link doesn't work for external links in gatsby